# How do I use pointers correctly with structs?

Tags: c, file, pointers, struct

I got confused with pointers while doing this code:

```
typedef struct Times{
    char time[100];
}Time;

Time *ptTimes(int tam, FILE *caminho){
    Time *times;
    times = (Time *)malloc((tam)*(sizeof(Time)));

    int i = 0;
    while(i < tam){
        fscanf(caminho, " %[^;];", (times->time));
        i++;
    }

    i=0;
    while (i < tam){
        printf("%s", times->time);
        times++;
        i++;
    }

    return(times);
}
```

The function `*ptTimes` was supposed to return a `Time` structure-pointer. What I intended to do was to creat a struct-pointer called `*times` and then make it point to several other structures allocated by `malloc` . I was trying to go through the allocated spaces and store the strings `time[100]` from a file. `tam` is the number of chars the program was supposed to read, it is a parameter sent from the main function.Also, I was trying to print in the screen what the structures have stored with `printf`.

I know I'm doing it wrong, the only thing `printf` showed on the screen was the last string on the file's list.

Here is an example of the `.txt` file:

```
Team1;
Team2;
Team3;
Team4;
```

I'm open for suggestions or ideas. I do need to use structures in this code.

Comment: [This information exists on the web. I don't have time to explain why you're using pointers wrong but I will link you to this VERY useful website.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)

Comment: @Mike Thanks, man, I'll read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `times->time` to `times[i].time`, and remove the `times++` at the end of the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: switched answer from pointer array to object array.

This line of code will always write to the first element in 'times', no matter the value of 'i':

```
fscanf(caminho, " %[^;];", (times->time));
```

It is equivalent to this line:

```
fscanf(caminho, " %[^;];", (times[0].time));
```

This is probably what you want:

```
fscanf(caminho, " %[^;];", (times[i].time));
```

You also need to get rid of the 'times++' line. The times pointer should continue to point to the memory that it allocated until you free it.

Comment: I tried to switch it for `times[i]->time` but it doesn't compile and it says "main.c:18:41: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Time’)"